# Counting unique users on Citrix?

Tags: licensing, citrix

I know very little about Citrix other than (correct me if I'm wrong) it runs a separate copy of windows, plus all apps etc, for each concurrent user of a citrix server.

If deploying an app I have written to a citrix server, is there any way to tell how many users there are in total?  e.g. can citrix give me a unique id for the client workstation or user account?  Or am I limited to detecting concurrent users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's sort of right, but not really. It isn't strictly speaking a completely separate copy of Windows. Each user gets their own "session" which is their own unique sandbox on the machine and there are shared services that get used across sessions.

All the stuff I'll talk about isn't really specific to Citrix. It is standard Windows stuff that would also apply if your users were RDPing into the server. There is a bunch of state you can query that maybe useful to you:

- The session ID will be unique for the lifetime of the session (however over time sessions come and go and the IDs do get re-used). This probably isn't the best choice for you as it is possible to have a user with multiple sessions on the same server. To learn more about this and other APIs, check out the Remote Desktop Services APIs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383464(v=vs.85).aspx
- You can query the current user identity, so you'll get the user name, domain, etc. Just use the standard identity APIs to do this.

Any app running in a session can query the above state for the current session. However if you want to query the state of other sessions running on the same server you would need local admin rights. So if you want some kind of generic mechanism that allows any instance of your app to determine how many unique users there are on the server, you're going to have to do a bunch of work.

E.g. create some additional long lived service that all instances of your app talk to report that they exist and then query to get the current unique user count.

If you want to get Citrix specific you can use something like the [XenApp Powershell SDK](http://www.citrix.com/downloads/xenapp/sdks/powershell-sdk.html), however depending on what you want to query, the current user will probably need some form of delegated admin permission in the Citrix farm.

That's a bit of a scatter gun answer - I've given you a bunch of different things to check out. Without more specific info about your use case it's hard to dig into more specific detail.

Comment: This is a good answer, a scatter gun is what I need right now.  Of course the trouble with querying user identity is that users could cheat by sharing accounts.  Is there any way around this?  Also going from what you say, will registry keys in  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` still do the right thing regardless of working in RDP/Citrix/etc?  i.e. `CURRENT_USER` be specific to the current user while `LOCAL_MACHINE` is shared by all users of the physical machine?

Comment: Yes those reg hives will work as expected, running under RDS/Citrix doesn't change how they work. It's pretty hard to completely protect yourself against malicious users. If users sharing accounts is really an issue for you, then all you can really do is count concurrent sessions on the server.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Citrix do you have? You can query EdgeSight (if pre 7.x) or Director for this sort of info and choose unique criteria to determine if a user is in more than one place (endpoint IP or name). Typically, if Citrix is setup with Session Sharing, sessions will roam so even if users were sharing logins, there could only be a single session running at a time. If another user logs into Citrix from another machine with the same credentials, the session will move to that new endpoint.

https://edgesightunderthehood.com/
https://wagthereal.com/tag/ms-sql/